# Is a holomorphic function with zero derivative on a close connected set constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that it is constant if the set is open and connected but I don't know why the condition of openness is necessary.

Comment: This is because the set could be a single point. Take $f(z) = z^2$, where $f' = 0$ on $\{0\}$.

Comment: @Justin The closed set needs to have a limit point (and it doesn't need to be connected, by the way).

Comment: @Justin - the statement is true if the set has more than one point.